# ASP.NET Core - Controllers in referenced assemblies

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I got a common library for .NET Core 3.1, in which I created a WEB API controller intended for sharing with multiple applications.

In order to add this to an application, I expected to something like this (from 3.0):

```
services.AddControllers()
        .PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
```

However, if I simply reference the common project, and call  `services.AddControllers()`, the controller get added automagickally..  which is kinda spooky. Apparently, AddControllers() traverses every assembly in all referenced projects, and just stupidly adds every controller it finds along the way.

I can't find documentation on this behaviour. The only way I can see to control this, is to create another project with the controller, and reference it when needed.

What's the correct (or intended) way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the intended/correct way of doing this is to not reference projects with controllers with other projects with controllers (even if you reference a project that references a project with a controller etc.).

i.e. any business logic should be referenced by both web api's seperately in something like a class library.

If you do arrive in this situation a work around is as follows;

```
services.AddControllers().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(o =>
            {
                o.ApplicationParts.Clear();
                o.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly));
            });
```

Where Startup is referencing the class you are in.

There is probably a slightly different way to handle it in .NET 6.